# How to prevent mouse right-clicking on a JPopupMenu

Tags: java, jtable, actionlistener, mouselistener

I am trying to implement a GUI with Java.
I bound a JPopupMenu to a JTable. The JPopupMenu becomes visible on mouse right-click on the JTable.

I managed to prevent mouse left-clicks on the JTable.
I haven't been able to prevent mouse left-clicks on any item of the JPopupMenu.
In fact each JMenuItem is bound to an ActionListener whose actionPerformed has no access to the mouse buttons.
May I associate a MouseListener with a JMenuItem?
If that is not possible then how can I make the JPopupMenu listen to mouse right-clicking only?

My goal is to reserve mouse left-clicks on the JTable for other tasks that are not related to the JPopupMenu.
I suppose I will need to bind the JTable to another Listener.
Can the same component (JTable) be associated with two different listeners?

Thank you in advance.

In the following I am pasting my code

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.AbstractListModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

//--------- Define ActionListener
class PopupActionListener implements ActionListener 
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
     System.out.println("Selected: " + actionEvent.getActionCommand());
}
}


public class MyNewGUI extends JFrame 
{
    
// INSTANCE VARIABLE/COMPONENTS
        private JPanel ctpMain;
        private JTextField txtNewPoint;
        private JLabel lblNewPoint;
        private JButton btnNewPoint;
        private JButton btnDeleteAll;
        private JButton btnDeleteUnused;
        private JScrollPane scrPoints;
        private JButton btnExit;
        DefaultTableModel pointsTableModel = new DefaultTableModel ();
        JTable tblPoints = new JTable(pointsTableModel);
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
        JMenuItem menuItemAddBefore;
        JMenuItem menuItemAddAfter;
        JMenuItem menuItemRemove;
        JMenuItem menuItemRename;

/**************************** Launch the application *********************************************/
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        } catch (Throwable e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                try
                {
                    MyNewGUI frame = new MyNewGUI();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) 
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    
//**************************  JFrame Class Constructor --> Create the frame   ***************************                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        */
    public MyNewGUI() 
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        setBounds(1050,200,800,800);
        setTitle("MyNewGUI");
        initComponents();
        
        btnExit = new JButton("Exit GUI");
        btnExit.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnExit.setBounds(14, 254, 101, 26);
        ctpMain.add(btnExit);
        setVisible(true);
        createEvents();
    }
    
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  This method contains all of the code for creating and initializing components
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void initComponents()
    {
        setTitle("MyGUI");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 1041, 779);
        ctpMain = new JPanel();
        ctpMain.setBounds(new Rectangle(5, 5, 0, 0));
        ctpMain.setAlignmentY(5.0f);
        ctpMain.setAlignmentX(5.0f);
        ctpMain.setSize(new Dimension(10, 10));
        ctpMain.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        ctpMain.setLocation(new Point(10, 10));
        ctpMain.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        ctpMain.setBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null));
        setContentPane(ctpMain);
        
        btnNewPoint = new JButton("Add New Point");
        
        btnNewPoint.setBounds(14, 55, 167, 29);
        btnNewPoint.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        
        txtNewPoint = new JTextField();
        txtNewPoint.setBounds(162, 14, 144, 29);
        txtNewPoint.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        txtNewPoint.setColumns(10);
        
        lblNewPoint = new JLabel("  Point Identifier");
        lblNewPoint.setLocation(new Point(14, 19));
        lblNewPoint.setSize(new Dimension(136, 19));
        lblNewPoint.setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(1);
        lblNewPoint.setAutoscrolls(true);
        lblNewPoint.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setBounds(179, 197, 1, 16);
        textArea.setText("");
        
        JPanel pnPoints = new JPanel();
        pnPoints.setBounds(321, 21, 211, 668);
        pnPoints.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 24));
        pnPoints.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null), "", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(64, 0, 64)));
        ctpMain.setLayout(null);
        ctpMain.add(btnNewPoint);
        ctpMain.add(txtNewPoint);
        ctpMain.add(lblNewPoint);
        ctpMain.add(textArea);
        ctpMain.add(pnPoints);
        pnPoints.setLayout(null);
        
        scrPoints = new JScrollPane();
        scrPoints.setBounds(0, 0, 206, 668);
        pnPoints.add(scrPoints);
        
// --------- Initialize JTable Model with points fromCliff's code
        pointsTableModel.addColumn("Point Names");
        pointsTableModel.insertRow(0, new Object[] { "ONE" });
        pointsTableModel.insertRow(0, new Object[] { "TWO" });   
        pointsTableModel.insertRow(0, new Object[] { "THREE" });     
        scrPoints.setViewportView(tblPoints);
        tblPoints.setFocusable(true);
        tblPoints.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        tblPoints.setVisible(true);
        
        
// --------- Initialize popupMenu with items ---
        PopupListener myListener = new PopupListener();
        menuItemAddBefore = new JMenuItem("Add Point Before");
    //  menuItemAddBefore.addMouseListener(myListener);
        menuItemAddAfter = new JMenuItem("Add Point After");
    //  menuItemAddAfter.addMouseListener(myListener);
        menuItemRemove = new JMenuItem("Remove Current Point");
    //  menuItemRemove.addMouseListener(myListener);
        menuItemRename = new JMenuItem("Rename Current Point");
    //  menuItemRename.addMouseListener(myListener);
        popupMenu.add(menuItemAddBefore);
        popupMenu.add(menuItemAddAfter);
        popupMenu.add(menuItemRemove);
        popupMenu.add(menuItemRename);
        
// --------- Set popupMenu to tblPoints
        tblPoints.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu); 
        tblPoints.addMouseListener(myListener);
    //  tblPoints.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
                
        btnDeleteAll = new JButton("Delete All Points");
        btnDeleteAll.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnDeleteAll.setBounds(14, 192, 167, 26);
        ctpMain.add(btnDeleteAll);
        
        btnDeleteUnused = new JButton("Delete Unused Points");
        btnDeleteUnused.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
        btnDeleteUnused.setBounds(14, 126, 205, 26);
        ctpMain.add(btnDeleteUnused);
    }
     
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  This method contains all of the code for creating events
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void createEvents() 
    {
        
//-------- Append Point To Point Names List ------------------------------------------------------------
        btnNewPoint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                String newPoint = txtNewPoint.getText();    
                pointsTableModel.addRow(new Object[] {newPoint});
                txtNewPoint.setText("");
            }
        });
        
//-------- Remove Unused Points From Point Names List ---------------------------------------------------
        btnDeleteUnused.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // TO BE DEVELOPED
            }
        });

//-------- Empty Point Names List --------------------------------------------------------------------------        
        btnDeleteAll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                while (pointsTableModel.getRowCount() > 0) 
                    pointsTableModel.removeRow(0);
            }
        });

//--------------- Button EXIT Handler --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        btnExit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                Object[] options = {"Exit Without Saving", "Exit With Saving","Cancel"};        //Custom button text
                int sel = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null ,
                    "Would you like to save your work before exiting ? ",
                    "EXIT WORK SESSION",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION,
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                    null,
                    options,
                    options[2]);
// Process Customer's Selection
                if (sel == 0) 
                {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose to exit your work session without saving!");
                     System.exit(0);    
                }
                if(sel == 1) 
                {
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose to save your work session before exiting !");
//                   if(lstPoints != null && !pointsTableModel.isEmpty())  // If JList contains Points
//                   {
//                       pointsList.clear();     // Empty Points storage
//                       System.out.print("\n pointsList after clear():  " + pointsList);       // DEBUG-PURPOSE
//                       System.out.print("\n pointsTableModel :  " + pointsTableModel);         // DEBUG-PURPOSE
//                       System.out.print("\n pointsTableModel size:  " + pointsTableModel.size() );        // DEBUG-PURPOSE
//                       System.out.print("\n");
//                       for(int i=0; i < pointsTableModel.size(); i++)
//                           pointsList.add(pointsTableModel.get(i));    // Move Points from JList to Points storage
//                       System.out.print("Saved Points:  " + pointsList + "\n");
//                   }else 
//                       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Ponts List is empty!"); 
//                   System.exit(0);    
                }
                if(sel == 2) 
                     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You changed your mind !");
            }
        });
        
//--------------- JMenuItem Handler To Add Item Before Selected JTable Row-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        menuItemAddBefore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                int row = tblPoints.getSelectedRow();
                  if (row == -1) 
                      return;
                System.out.print("Add Point to tblPoints Before Row:  " + row + "\n");
                String precedingPointName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Following Point Name");
                System.out.println(precedingPointName);   
                pointsTableModel.insertRow(row, new Object[] {precedingPointName});
                tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        }); 
                
//--------------- JMenuItem Handler To Add Item After Selected JTable Row-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        menuItemAddAfter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                int row = tblPoints.getSelectedRow();
                  if (row == -1 || !tblPoints.isCellEditable(row,0)) 
                      return;
                String value = tblPoints.getValueAt(row, 0).toString(); 
                System.out.print("Add Point to tblPoints After PointName: " + value + " On  Row:  " + row + "\n");
                String followingPointName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Following Point Name");
                System.out.println(followingPointName);   
                pointsTableModel.insertRow(row +1, new Object[] {followingPointName});
                tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });         
        
//--------------- JMenuItem Handler To Remove Selected JTable Row----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        menuItemRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                int row = tblPoints.getSelectedRow();
                  if (row == -1) 
                      return;
                System.out.print("Remove Point at tblPoints rown:  " + row + "\n");
                pointsTableModel.removeRow(tblPoints.getSelectedRow());
                tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        }); 
        
//--------------- JMenuItem Handler To Rename Item At Selected JTable Row----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        menuItemRename.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) 
            {
                int row = tblPoints.getSelectedRow();
                 if (row == -1) 
                      return;
                 System.out.print("Rename Point at tblPoints rown:  " +  row + "\n");
                 String replacingPointName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Current Point Replacing Name");
                 tblPoints.getModel().setValueAt(replacingPointName, row, 0);
                 tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
            }
        });         

    }  //-----------------------------------  End Of  createEvents() Method ----------------------------------------------------------------------  
    
// ********* Inner classes *********

    public class PopupListener extends MouseAdapter
    {
         public PopupListener()                 //  Default Constructor
         {
            System.out.print("\n Default PopupListener Constructor engaged \n ");
         }
         
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
         
         {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3)
            {
                  Point p = e.getPoint();
                  Component c = e.getComponent();
                  int row = tblPoints.rowAtPoint(p);
                  System.out.print("\n `Selected row:  " + row + "\n");
                  if (row == -1)
                  {
                      tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                      return;
                  }
                  else
                      tblPoints.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
            }
            else
                tblPoints.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I’m pretty sure you should just remove your MouseListener.  The default behavior for a popup-menu already reserves the left mouse button for the table.  Left-clicking on menu items *should* activate them, because popup menus are on top of other components.

Comment: I commented out line 214 in my posted code. 
   Let's assume JTable contains the following 6 rows:
   ONE
   TWO
   THREE
   FOUR
   FIVE
   SIX

  Let's assume JPopupMenu contains the following items:
   ADD POINT BEFORE
   ADD POINT AFTER
   REMOVE CURRENT POINT
   RENAME CURRENT POINT

 I left-click on the ONE row that becomes highlighted.
 I right-click on the SIX row. JPopupMenu becomes visible. I right-click on item "REMOVE CURRENT POINT" 
 The left-click selected row is removed rather than the right-clicked row
 that brought up the JPopupMenu.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly: you want right-clicking on a row to select that row, if it’s not already selected, before showing the popup menu.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Mouse right-clicks should select the row on which the chosen JPopupMenu action (item) is carried out.

Comment: I would like to reserve mouse left-clicks on JTable to select point names (strings) used by another GUI component to identify a line (it needs two points). Is it possible to register two different MouseListeners  to the same JTable?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand.  When the user left-clicks on a table cell, you want the row selected and you also want something else to happen?  Won’t that be confusing?

Comment: This is a GUI for a Java project aimed at helping maxillo-facial surgeons trace lines on a CT image of a skull and take measurements.
The implemented JTable contains point names.
Another JTable will contain line names. 
A line can be defined by selecting start snd end point from the existing JTable.
Or selecting a point and entering an angle value.
Or selecting an existing line and a distance to generate a parallel line

Comment: I’m not sure I fully understand the behavior you’re describing, since I don’t understand the need for an additional MouseListener.  Why not just examine the row selection in each table?

Comment: The surgeon clicks on a number of anatomical points that get listed in the current JTable P1, P2, P3,..).
Then he/she starts defining line segments that will be listed in a another JTable.
For example, the surgeon asks the program to draw a segment between point P1 and point P2 that are already stored 
in the current JTable.
How can he/she select the segment start and end point if not by left-clicking on the existing JTable?

Comment: Doesn’t left-clicking in the table already select rows?  That is standard behavior for all JTables.  Why do you need a custom MouseListener for that?

Comment: Say the user left-clicks on JTable row_1 then right-clicks on row_10 then chooses "DELETE ROW" from the JPopupMenu. Consequently, row_1, rather than row_10, will be removed. That isn't very clear for surgeons. So I make sure the row is selected by right-clicking.  I need to use JTable left-clicking to allow the surgeon to pick two points (rows) and draw a line.  I may be able to process left-clicking within the MouseListener. At the moment I only process right-clicking. This way I may avoid a second MouseListener bound to JTable.

Comment: We agree on my initial interpretation:  you want right-clicking on a row to select that row, if it’s not already selected, before showing the popup menu.   I still don’t understand why you need a special MouseListener to let the user select two rows in a single table.

Comment: In the current MouseListener i only process right-clicks. I now have to allow selection of two distinguished rows (points) without disrupting the working right-clicking that is used to pick a JTable row and and item from the JPopupMenu.  I expect a lot of headache

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want right-clicking to select a table row if the row under the mouse pointer isn’t already selected, before showing the popup menu.

For that, you should remove `tblPoints.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);` and instead display your JPopupMenu yourself, using your own MouseListener and key mappings.  Normally, setComponentPopupMenu takes care of all of that, but you will need to customize that behavior.

```
MouseListener mousePopupListener = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        showPopup(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        showPopup(event);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
        showPopup(event);
    }

    private void showPopup(MouseEvent event) {
        int row = tblPoints.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && !tblPoints.isRowSelected(row)) {
            tblPoints.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
        }

        if (popupMenu.isPopupTrigger(event)) {
            popupMenu.show(tblPoints, event.getX(), event.getY());
        }
    }
};
tblPoints.addMouseListener(mousePopupListener);
```

It is crucial to respond to mouse-down, mouse-up, and mouse-clicked events, because different platforms have different behaviors for popup menus.

However… this is not enough.  Swing applications need to be *accessible*—meaning, among other things, they need to support using the keyboard to activate controls.  (For instance, users can tab to a button and press space to ‘push’ it.)  On most platforms, popup menus can be activated using the menu key on a PC keyboard (which usually has a ‘’ symbol on it), which Java represents as KeyEvent.VK_CONTEXT_MENU, as well as with Shift-F10.

```
String actionName = "showPopup";
Action keyboardMenuDisplayer = new AbstractAction(actionName) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        Point location;

        PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            location = info.getLocation();
            SwingUtilities.convertPointFromScreen(location, tblPoints);
        } else {
            int focusedRow =
                tblPoints.getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
            int focusedColumn =
                tblPoints.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().getLeadSelectionIndex();
            if (focusedRow >= 0 && focusedColumn >= 0) {
                Rectangle cell =
                    tblPoints.getCellRect(focusedRow, focusedColumn, false);
                location = cell.getLocation();
            } else {
                location = new Point();
            }
        }
        
        popupMenu.show(tblPoints, location.x, location.y);
    }
};

tblPoints.getActionMap().put(actionName, keyboardMenuDisplayer);

InputMap inputMap = tblPoints.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("CONTEXT_MENU"), actionName);
inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift F10"), actionName);
```

Comment: Many thanks. This is really professional s/w development.

Comment: My goal is to handle mouse right-clicking for tblPoints row selection and also for displaying the popupMenu.
The next expected event is a mouse click (Right ot Left) on an item of the popupMenu. That will trigger an action performed
 on the current selected tblPoints row.
If  the mouse is clicked ***outside*** the popupMenu then I need to deselect the selected tblPoints row.
How can I detect a mouse click outside the popupMenu?

Comment: When the user selects "Line Between Two Points" from a ComboBox then I have to inhibit any button click, mouse Right-Click and allow only mouse Left-clicking on a tblPoints row. 
How can I disable any event  other than mouse Left-click on tblPoints?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to manage mouse behavior that doesn’t need to be managed.  Mouse clicking already works properly:  right-click to show a popup menu, click outside of the menu to dismiss it.  All of this is normal behavior.  Whether a mouse click outside of the popup menu only dismisses the popup menu and is otherwise ignored, or is processed by the window where the click occurs, is system dependent behavior.  You should not try to override that behavior.  If it works a certain way in all other applications, it should work that way in your application.